# Execute cutom javascript in report server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I followed this [blog](https://braingrabber.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/ms-reporting-services-add-javascript-to-a-report/) to insert custom javascript into my report.

1. I open report properties and referenced the library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.dll".
   [image]
2. I copied System.Web.dll to "\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin"
3. Under report properties > code I add the function:

   ```
   Function WriteHTML (ByVal Msg AS String) AS String
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Msg)
   Return “”
   End Function
   ```
4. Inserted a hidden textbox to the report and set expression to:

   ```
   Code.WriteHTML("<script> console.log('hello world');</script>")
   ```

5 ) I deployed the report without any error.

But if I run the report in the browser no output is written to browser console. Any suggestions, do I miss something? Do I have to edit the rssrvpolicy.config as it mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/custom-assemblies/deploying-a-custom-assembly?view=sql-server-ver15) under point 3?

I found a second [tutorial](https://direit.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/ssrs-use-custom-javascript-to-call-a-report-in-a-new-tabwindow/) which describes an other method to execute a custom script in your report. But in my case I can't find any js file under "\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER".

Comment: WordPress blogs are Evil for messing up code in subtle ways. Does it work better if you replace the "Smart Quotes" in `Return “”` with normal ASCII quotes in `Return ""`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning good point. But no effect. I also tryed `$( document ).ready(function() {
 console.log('hello world');
});`.

Comment: Any solution in the end?